# How use Jekyll toc in html templates? (out of *.md post files)

Tags: html, templates, jekyll

I am wondering why the TOC (surrounded by {{ }} or not in any kind of fashion is not rendered when used in the Jekyll post.html template:

```
---
layout: default
---
<article class="post" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

  <header class="post-header">
    <h1 class="post-title" itemprop="name headline">{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p class="post-meta"><time datetime="{{ page.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" itemprop="datePublished">{{ page.date | date: "%A, %B %-d, %Y" }}</time>{% if page.author %} • <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">{{ page.author }}</span></span>{% endif %}</p>
  </header>

  <div class="post-content" itemprop="articleBody">

    >> * TOC  <<
    >> {:toc} <<

    {{ content }}
  </div>

</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

The table of contents feature you are describing is a feature of the kramdown converter, which means that you have to add the toc generation code to your markdown file content. As I see you are adding it to `html.

I use it in the following way on my blog in my `.md` files:

`* TOC
{:toc}`

Please note that you can use the `.no_toc` classname to exclude headers from content generation.

`# Contents header
{:.no_toc}`

This means that you can to something like this in your post `.md` file, and that's another reason to add the toc to your content:

`# Table of contents
{:.no_toc}`

`* TOC
{:toc}`

`# Heading 1`

`## Heading 2`

Please also make sure that you set `markdown: kramdown` in your `_config.yml`. (kramdown is the default on GitHub pages).

Comment: I know how it works with markdown files, my point was to add it to a html template in order to not bother myself adding it manually in every markdown file...